# php/html add link to table <TD>

Tags: html, hyperlink, html-table, addition

How can I add a link to my `td` tag from a `table`?
`onClick` doesn't work. I could use a good example.

My `td` tag:

```
$world .= ('<td background="images/world/Heli.jpg" border="1"></td>');
```

A link:

```
<a href="?site=world&action=showvillage&id=' . getVillageID(($xm2), ($ym2)) . '"></a>
```

Comment: what are you asking here? I can't make sense of your question...

Comment: I suspect you need to drop a <a name="someid"></a> inside your table element so you can link to it in another <a href=#someid"> tag, but your question needs to be a lot clearer...

Answer (score 1):

If you want the link to behave such that the entire  (cell) is clickable and navigates to the link, you could wrap it in an  (anchor) tag like this:

```
<a href="?site=world&action=showvillage&id=' . getVillageID(($xm2), ($ym2)) . '">
    <td background="images/world/Heli.jpg" border="1">&nbsp;</td>
</a>
```

I don't know how your `$world` variable is being used, so you'll have to arrive at the above formatting on your own.